# Prove using the limit definition of a derivative an equation relating total and partial derivatives of a two variable function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

1. I've been trying to prove the following equation which relates the total derivative to the partial derivatives of a two variable function $$V(r, h)$$, namely $$\frac{dV}{dr} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial h}\frac{dh}{dr} $$ using only limits. This isn't a homework question but just something I want to learn how to do.
2. I was able to do so for the special case of $$V(r, h) = \frac{\pi r^2h}{3}$$ as follows (volume of a cone with height h and radius r):
   $$\frac{dV}{dr} = \lim\limits_{\Delta r \to 0} \frac{V(r+\Delta r, h(r+\Delta r))-V(r,h(r))}{\Delta r} 
   \\=\lim\limits_{\Delta r \to 0} \left(\frac{\pi(r+\Delta r)^2h(r+\Delta r)}{3\Delta r} - \frac{\pi r^2}{3\Delta r}\right) 
   \\=\lim\limits_{\Delta r \to 0} \frac{\pi r^2h(r+\Delta r) + 2\pi r\Delta h(r+\Delta r)+\pi(\Delta r)^2h(r+\Delta r) - \pi r^2h(r)}{3\Delta r} 
   \\=\lim\limits_{\Delta r \to 0} \left(\frac{\pi r^2}{3}\frac{h(r+\Delta r)-h(r)}{\Delta r}\right) + \lim\limits_{\Delta r \to 0} \frac{2\pi rh(r+\Delta r)}{3} + \lim\limits_{\Delta r \to 0} \frac{\pi(\Delta r)h(r+\Delta r)}{3}
   \\=\frac{\pi r^2}{3}\frac{dh}{dr}+\frac{2\pi rh(r)}{3} + 0
   \\= \frac{\partial V}{\partial h}\frac{dh}{dr} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial r}
   $$
3. I wasn't able to get anywhere with an arbitrary function. The thing that's making it difficult for me is there being two variables h and r in the limit expression. I'm thinking I have to do a change of variables or use the composition limit law but it's just a guess and I haven't been making any progress.

$$\frac{dV}{dr} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial h}\frac{dh}{dr}$$ which in limit form is:

$$
\lim\limits_{\Delta r \to 0} \frac{V(r+\Delta r, h(r+\Delta r))-V(r,h(r))}{\Delta r} 
\\=\lim\limits_{\Delta r \to 0} \frac{V(r+\Delta r, h)-V(r,h)}{\Delta r} 
+\lim\limits_{\Delta h \to 0} \frac{V(r, h+\Delta h)-V(r,h)}{\Delta h}\lim\limits_{\Delta r \to 0} \frac{h(r+\Delta r)-h(r)}{\Delta r}
$$
which is what I want to prove.

Help would be much appreciated.
-Jay

Comment: You can write your difference quotient $$\frac{V(r+\Delta r,h(r+\Delta r))-V(r,h(r))}{\Delta r}$$ as $$\frac{V(r+\Delta r,h(r+ \Delta r))-V(r,h(r+ \Delta r))}{\Delta r}+\frac{V(r,h(r+\Delta r))-V(r,h(r))}{h(r+\Delta r)-h(r)}\cdot\frac{h(r+\Delta r)-h(r)}{\Delta r}$$

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand after making a few substitutions and trying this on paper. Do I have to take limits of both sides of the equation as you've written them twice, the first time lim dh->0 and second lim dr->0 to get the final result? I tried taking limits just once and it didn't work out so I tried doing it twice..

Comment: You only want to take the limit as $\Delta r$ approaches $0$. It should be clear that $$\frac{V(r+\Delta r,h(r+\Delta r))-V(r,h(r+\Delta r))}{\Delta r}\rightarrow V_r(r,h(r))$$  and $$\frac{h(r+\Delta r)-h(r)}{\Delta r}\rightarrow h'(r)$$ To see why $$\frac{V(r,h(r+ \Delta r))-V(r,h(r))}{h(r+ \Delta r)-h(r)}\rightarrow V_h(r,h(r))$$ I would write $h(r+\Delta r)\approx h'(r)\Delta r+h(r)$ and deduce $$\frac{V(r,h(r+ \Delta r))-V(r,h(r))}{h(r+ \Delta r)-h(r)}\approx \frac{V(r,h(r)+\tau)-V(r,h(r))}{\tau}$$ where $\tau=h'(r)\Delta r\rightarrow \tau$ as $\Delta r \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I should warn you that is *not* a formal argument; in fact, this manipulation will work out if you assume there exists an open set $\mathcal{O}$ containing $r$ such that $h(x)\neq h(r)$ for all $x\in \mathcal{O}-\{r\}$

Answer (score 0):

<s>derivative has a characterization that if $g : A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at a point $x \in A$, then
$$g(x + h) = g(x) + g'(x)h + o(h),$$
where $r(h) = o(q(h))$ means $\frac{r(h)}{q(h)} \to 0$ as $h \to 0$
Now assume $f : A \subseteq \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$, and $x : B \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $y : B \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then
\begin{align}
f(x(t + h), y(t + h)) &= f(x + x'h + o(h), y + y'h + o(h)) \\
&= f(x + x'h + o(h), y) + f_y(x + x'h + o(h), y)(y'h + o(h)) + o(y'h + o(h)) \\
&= f(x + x'h + o(h), y) + f_y(x + x'h + o(h), y)(y'h + o(h)) + o(h) \\
&= f(x, y) + f_x(x, y)(x'h + o(h)) + o(x'h + o(h)) + f_y(x + x'h + o(h), y)(y'h + o(h)) + o(h) \\
&= f(x, y) + f_x(x, y)(x'h + o(h)) + o(h) + f_y(x + x'h + o(h), y)(y'h + o(h)) + o(h) \\
&= f(x, y) + f_x(x, y)(x'h + o(h)) + f_y(x + x'h + o(h), y)(y'h + o(h)) + o(h)
\end{align}
Now subtract $f(x, y)$ and divide by $h$ and let $h \to 0$ to get
$$\frac{d}{dt}f(x, y) = f_x(x, y)x'(t) + f_y(x, y)y'(t).$$
Whenever I omitted the argument of $x$ and $y$ I mean it to be $t$.
There is a flaw, in that I assumed $f_y$ to be continuous at $(x(t), y(t))$. I'm not sure how to avoid this or if this is necessary for the result to hold.</s>

The answer is wrong.